# DS-160: Contact person in home country

Tags: usa, student-visa

In form DS-160 (for US F-1 visa) at the end it is mentioned that:

NOTE: You have indicated that you will be studying in some capacity while in the United States. List at least two contacts in your country of residence who can verify the information that you have provided on this application. Do not list immediate family members or other relatives.

Whose names can I possibly write here? Will those two persons be really contacted?

Additional information : I am a masters' student in India going to US for PhD.

Comment: No professor knows what you're doing?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify